# Is the "baroque" tag inconsistent?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have a `classical-period` tag and a `romantic-period` tag, but then we have the `baroque` tag. Is it worth changing this to "baroque-period" for the sake of consistency/my OCD?

After all, as Richard pointed out:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJMtGhqPCW0

Comment: The famous idiom's lesser-known sibling: if it *is* "baroque," fix it!

Comment: Done - synonym created and merged